# How to get delivery report for a specific contact number while sending sms to multiple contacts in android?

Tags: android

I am sending `sms` to multiple contacts and at that time I want to get the delivery report for which number I am sending `sms`.How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

using extras data on pending intent, send unique string as key to identify which sms is delivered/sent

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835052/how-to-know-which-sms-is-sent-delivered-from-android-broadcastreceiver)