# How to Know which Sms is sent/delivered from Android BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I have made a simple app to send multiple SMS on android. I cannot find which sms is Sent/Delivered, because the delivery notification does not tell for which it is.

**here is my code :**

```
    this.destination = data[0];
    this.body = data[1];

    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(aCtx, 0, new Intent(Cons.SMS_SENT),0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(aCtx, 0, new Intent(Cons.SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, body, piSend, piDelivered);
```

Then I use broadcast receiver to get delivery status

```
public class DeliverSMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    switch (getResultCode())
    {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(Cons.TAGS+" RK","RESULT_OK=> DELIVER");
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(Cons.TAGS+" RK","RESULT_CANCELED");
            break;
    }}
}
```

And Here Is my activity :

```
public class SenderPage extends Activity {
private EditText txtRecepients = null;
private EditText inputSMSText = null;
private Button btnSendSMS = null;

private final BroadcastReceiver outgoingSMSBR = new OutgoingSMSBroadcastReceiver();
private final BroadcastReceiver deliverSMSBR = new DeliverSMSBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.senderpage);
    Log.i(Cons.TAGS, "Sender Page Start");

    this.setTitle("Send Message");

    this.txtRecepients = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRecepients);
    this.inputSMSText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSMSText);
    this.btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);

    txtRecepients.setText("087722079905");      //087722079905 //081214571542

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(SenderPage.this, "Clicked send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String txtRecepients = SenderPage.this.txtRecepients.getText().toString();
            String inputSMSText = SenderPage.this.inputSMSText.getText().toString();

            new Sender(SenderPage.this,Cons.TAGS).execute(txtRecepients, inputSMSText);
        }
    });

    //txtRecepients.getText().toString();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(outgoingSMSBR, new IntentFilter(Cons.SMS_SENT));
    registerReceiver(deliverSMSBR, new IntentFilter(Cons.SMS_DELIVERED));
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(outgoingSMSBR);
    unregisterReceiver(deliverSMSBR);
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

When I sent more than one SMS, then how can I get the delivery information to make sure which SMS is delivered?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer by added intent extras to pending intent with sms create datetime, then update sms status based on datetime that sent by extras data, here is the snippet :

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent(Cons.SMS_SENT);
sentIntent.putExtra("createdTime", createdTime);

Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(Cons.SMS_SENT);
deliveryIntent.putExtra("createdTime", createdTime);
```

then I can identify which sms is sent/delivery by created time

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String smsDateTimeAsID = intent.getStringExtra("createdTime");
 }
```

Comment: Hi, what's the value of Cons.SMS_SENT please?

Comment: @Yoesoff... hi, could you ensure us that your double broadcastlistener has no problem at all? Seems my code that has double BroadcastListener doesnt call at all....

Answer (score 0):

Cons.SMS_SENT and Cons.SMS_DELIVERED Values

```
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
```