# Android SMS receiving: I get pdus in receivers null

Tags: android, sms

i have a problem with delivering sms receiver. I set in `Manifest` permissions and intent filter, in `Activity` - sms is created and `BroadcastReceiver` catch intent as in tutorial

Here is code from `Activity`

```
        try {
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_RECEIVED";
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact.getPhone(), null, message, null, deliveredPI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Sms do not sent");
        }
```

Here is permissions in `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    ...
    <receiver android:name="com.uniquare.sms.globals.DeliveredReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and part of `Receivers`

```
 public class DeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "DeliveredReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive()");
    //get the SMS message passed in
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String phone = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        //retrieve the SMS message received
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    .....
```

And there is something strange for me. If i send sms to my current device, `BroadcastReceiver` works fine. But if i send to other users from contact list `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't work at all.

I try to set `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` instead of `SMS_RECEIVED` in `Activity` `PendingIntent`:

```
            String DELIVERED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

in this case `DeliveredReceiver` is working, `onReceive` is called but when I try to get `pdus` from `Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");` I get `null`.

Do you have the same problems? Could u suggest me smth?

Comment: I don't seem to fully understand, so you're saying when sending and sms from the android device your BroadcastReceiver doesn't catch it? If this is the case, BroadcastReceiver can't catch sent sms's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages (at least for now)

Comment: I want to catch delivered status of sms that was sent. Can i use receivers for catching all received sms and get delivered status from? Can i find out is sms delivered or not?

Comment: SMS delivery status is a feature that can be enabled on phone settings   IIRC. For what you want maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835052/how-to-know-which-sms-is-sent-delivered-from-android-broadcastreceiver